# Subtracting data frames in Python returning NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to subtract the second columns of two csv files(mycsv.csv, mycsv2.csv), while keeping the first columns of both the same. It does the latter perfectly fine as you can see below, but the prices columns (2 and 4), just give back NaN.

```
     col2  col4
col1            
MMM    NaN   NaN
WBAI   NaN   NaN
WUBA   NaN   NaN
EGHT   NaN   NaN
AHC    NaN   NaN
```

I don't know where this error is coming from, so I apologize for some much code. Thank you for any help you can give!

I'm trying to subtract the second columns of two csv files(mycsv.csv, mycsv2.csv), while keeping the first columns of both the same. It does the latter perfectly fine as you can see below, but the prices columns (2 and 4), just give back NaN.

```
     col2  col4
col1            
MMM    NaN   NaN
WBAI   NaN   NaN
WUBA   NaN   NaN
EGHT   NaN   NaN
AHC    NaN   NaN
```

I don't know where this error is coming from, so I apologize for some much code. Thank you for any help you can give!

```
data_sheet1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\sss\\Downloads\\Book1.xlsx')
data_impor = data_sheet1['DDD'].tolist()

def get_ohlc(symbols): 
    data = get_quotes(symbol=symbols)
    symbols_and_lastPrices = [] #create empty list
    for symbol in symbols:
        symbols_and_lastPrices.append([symbol, data[symbol]['lastPrice']]) #append [symbol, lastPrice]-pairs to list.
    return symbols_and_lastPrices #return list


csv_data = get_ohlc(data_impor) #save returned list

#write csv

with open ("mycsv.csv", "w" , newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['col1', 'col2'])
    thewriter.writerows(csv_data) #write all data rows at the same time

with open('mycsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

time.sleep(2)

csv2_data = get_ohlc(data_impor) #save returned list

#write csv

with open ("mycsv2.csv", "w" , newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['col3', 'col4'])
    thewriter.writerows(csv2_data) #write all data rows at the same time

with open('mycsv2.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

df1  = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', index_col = 'col1')
df2  = pd.read_csv('mycsv2.csv', index_col = 'col3')
df3 = df1.sub(df2)
print(df3.head())
```

Comment: pandas does mostly all operations using data alignmet on indexes.  Both row indexes and column headers.  Therefore, I think you your problem is that you are importing csv files with different column headers.  To subtract the two, you need to rename one of your dataframes from your csv import to match the other column header.

Comment: Thank you! I am a but confused by what you're trying to say. So I need to rename what I call the data frame? I don't really see what that has to do with the column header

Comment: See the example in the answer below.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does most operations using index alignment, see this example.  Both the row indexes in a dataframe and the column headers are `pd.Index` so pandas will align the data both horizontally (rows) and vertically (columns).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

file1 = StringIO("""No,col2,col4
MMM,10,10
WBAI,20,20
WUBA,40,40
SCOT,50,50""")

file2= StringIO("""No,col1,col4
MMM,5,5
WBAI,15,15
WUBA,35,35
N300,50,50""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, index_col=0)
print(df1)
#       col2  col4
# No              
# MMM     10    10
# WBAI    20    20
# WUBA    40    40
# SCOT    50    50


df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, index_col=0)
print(df2)
#       col1  col4
# No              
# MMM      5     5
# WBAI    15    15
# WUBA    35    35
# N300    50    50

print(df1 - df2)
#       col1  col2  col4
# No                    
# MMM    NaN   NaN   5.0
# N300   NaN   NaN   NaN
# SCOT   NaN   NaN   NaN
# WBAI   NaN   NaN   5.0
# WUBA   NaN   NaN   5.0
```

Note, you have both col1 and col2 in the result and are NaN because alignment

```
print(df1 - df2.rename(columns={'col1':'col2'}))
#       col2  col4
# No              
# MMM    5.0   5.0
# N300   NaN   NaN
# SCOT   NaN   NaN
# WBAI   5.0   5.0
# WUBA   5.0   5.0
```

Here, we have correct column alignment but there are two indexes that don't line up